# How to prove $(\sec^2(a)+\tan^2(a))(\csc^2(a)+\cot^2(a))=1+2\sec^2(a)\cdot\csc^2(a)$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I prove that
$$\left(\sec^2(a)+\tan^2(a)\right)\left(\csc^2(a)+\cot^2(a)\right)=1+2\sec^2(a)\cdot\csc^2(a)?$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This problem reminded me of my high school teacher, who advised me to always convert to sine and cosine if I am not sure how to proceed, this worked nicely here. \begin{align*} (\sec^2{(a)}+\tan^2{(a)})(\csc^2{(a)}+\cot^2{(a)}) &= \left( \frac{1+\sin^2{(a)}}{\cos^2{(a)}}\right)\left( \frac{1+\cos^2{(a)}}{\sin^2{(a)}}\right) \\
& = \frac{2+\sin^2{(a)}\cos^2{(a)}}{\sin^2{(a)}\cos^2{(a)}} \\
&= 1+2\csc^2{(a)}\sec^2{(a)}\end{align*}